# Cannot see any exception message even under the desired condition

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, error-handling

I am newbie of Java field.

I want to throw error and get error message from the body when I call a parameter(in my e.g., title) is missing. But I cannot.

I attach the whole of my code, and in MovieListController.java file, I use if/else conditional statement in order to throw exception.

Actually, I have no much idea of java yet. So please let me know what part I should revise or make additionally.

Thanks.

I am using eclipse 2019-03, with Spring-boot v2.1.4 and Maven build.

MovieList.java

```
package movie;

public class MovieList {

    private final long year;
    private final String title;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public long getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public MovieList( long year, String title) {
        this.title = title;
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

MovieListController.java

```
package movie;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class MovieListController {

    private static final String template = "The movie - %s ( %d )";

    @RequestMapping(value="/movielist", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public MovieList movie(
            @RequestParam(value="title") String title,
            @RequestParam(value="year") long year,
            @RequestHeader(value="test") String header
            ) {
        if(title == null) {
            throw new MyException("test execution");
        } else {
            return new MovieList( year, String.format(template, title, year));
        }
    }
}
```

Application.java including main function

```
package movie;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

MyException.java

```
package movie;

import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseStatus;

@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public MyException(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

Comment: What actually happens when you hit `GET /movielist`?  An exception should be getting thrown.

Comment: Does the method actually get called, have you tried debugging?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The build was succeeded, and I tested by using Postman. I can see JSON data including message, but there's no "test execution" which I wrote in MovieListController.java

Comment: I don't even know where you're looking (maybe the standard error log), but this would be a good time to setup a custom logger, e.g. `log4j`.  You should be logging from your custom exceptions.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I clicked Maven build first, and then execute the Spring Boot App. and... I think you are right. I will try to setup the custom logger first. Thanks.

Comment: That's probably the best suggestion.  Now, the output is going _somewhere_, but obviously not where you want, and a logger is the best way to control this behavior.